# Scaling values for LSTM

Tags: lstm, feature-scaling

I have the following time series data set

[image]

Each row is a unique Item, and each column shows the amount purchased per day. There are a total of 33 columns.

I'm taking the first 32 columns(leaving out the last column, which will be my target) as my training set, and the last 32 rows (leaving out the first column) as my testing set

```
X_train = dataset[:, :-1] # taking all columns except the last column

y_train = dataset[:, -1:] # setting the last column to be the target

X_test = dataset[:, 1:] # taking all columns expect the first column
```

I'm going to feed `X_train` and `y_train` in my LSTM model, and use the model to perform prediction on `X_test`.

Now, I wish to performing minmax scaling on `dataset` before performing training,  but I have some questions:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaled_dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
```

This has obvious data leakages, because the scaler is fitted with the test values.

I thought of creating 2 scalers, one for the training set, and one for the target

```
scaler_x = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaled_all_data = scaler_x.fit_transform(dataset[:, :-1])
scaled_y = scaler_y.fit_transform(dataset[:, -1:])
```

I'm not sure if that's the right approach. I've already tried searching for answers, but their situation is not quite like mine, or the questions are unanswered yet.

Any advice on how I should perform value scaling?

Comment: When scaling features, you should scale the training data and store the min and max values. Then, the test set has to be scaled with those values, not with the max and min of the test set

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not scale the values as the very first step? Import your values, scale the values ***and then*** do your splits for training/test/etc.

Comment: You cannot fit the scaler based on the whole dataset. Otherwise, features of the Test set will flow back to the Train set. You have to scale based on Train set ONLY, and then use the Train scaling parameters to process the Test set. That's the only way to actually assess a model's performance